# merge array as object into another array

Tags: php, json

I have 2 array in php (I use echo json_encode()) to show u the output :

echo json_encode($arr);

```
[{'a':1}]
```

and echo json_encode($arr2);

```
[{'something':1},{'something2':2}]
```

When I do $arr[] = $arr2; it output this

```
[{'a':1}[{'something':1},{'something2':2}]]
```

what I want is

```
[{'a':1},{'something':1},{'something2':2}]
```

Comment: Do this: `json_encode(array_merge($arr, $arr2))`

Comment: fyi, if using associated arrays and the same key is in both arrays, with different values, then there will only be one entry in the result list for that value. It will have the value taken from the last array in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `array_merge`:

```
$res = array_merge($arr, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_merge($arr, $arr2);
json_encode($result);

//Output:
//[{'a':1},{'something':1},{'something2':2}]
```